# Can iPhone take photos at background?

Tags: iphone, sdk, background, photo

Recently I use NSTimer to repeat taking photos, it'll show on the screen.

This is the problem:

I need to execute my app. & taking photos at the same time.
So, does there any way to take photos at background?

I'll appreciate for any opinions~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into `NSThread`'s [`detachNewThreadSelector:toTarget:withObject:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000311-CHDEBGEC) method.

For example:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(takePictures) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

Somewhere else in your class, you'd have:

```
- (void) takePictures {
   // insert code to take pictures...
}
```